# awk -F" " delimit by space greater than 1

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'm trying to parse the results of `nmcli dev wifi` which produces a result like this:

```
*  SSID                 MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
   Prk                  Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█            
   VIDEOTRON2255        Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
   a space              Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
*  TNCAP4D0B18          Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__
```

Initially I was just parsing using `awk -F" "` which worked for almost all cases. I'm finding any wifi network with `a space` in it throws this off completely.

So I instead try using two spaces instead of one this didn't produce the results I expected. How can I consistently parse the columns in the above output?

Current script is something like this:

```
nmcli dev wifi | sed 's/\*//g' > /tmp/scan
networks=$(cat /tmp/scan | awk -F"  " '{print $1}' | sed '1d')
# ...
bars=$(cat /tmp/scan | awk -F"  " '{print $6}' | sed '1d')
```

Comment: what about `awk -F'\t'`?

Comment: @Jesse_b just tried it now and didn't work

Comment: it's not clear. what do you want to put in the networks and bars variables? in the booth case I typed awk command without '-F' option : I've got the list of the networks and the db of the signal.

Comment: At least with recent versions of `nmcli`, you can avoid needing to parse the output by specifying exactly what fields you want (and in what order) e.g. `networks=$(nmcli -t -f ssid dev wifi)`. There's also an option to print in a machine-parsable mode.

Comment: @dubis that is what you should have but it won't work if a wifi network has a space in the name.

Comment: @steeldriver good to know but I'm afraid of using that approach. If each time I run `nmcli` the wifi is again scanned how can I be sure that the network list won't have changed? (e.g. could I be sure the 7th entry in the SSID field is actually the same network as the 7th entry in the security field)

Comment: Huh? what does that have to do with how you parse it? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm converting `nmcli` into a json object to be passed to web developers as an api.

Comment: In that case you should (IMHO) almost certainly using the `--mode multiline` format if your version of `nmcli` supports it - which gives you colon-delimited key-value pairs out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the first line to find at which position each column starts, then parse the other lines based on column numbers. For example, the following script prints column 2 which is the SSID.

```
nmcli_output=$(nmcli dev wifi)
printf %s\\n "$nmcli_output" | awk -v column=2 '
    NR==1 {
        i=1; p=1;
        while(match($0,/^[^ ]+ +/)) {
            a[i++] = p;
            p += RLENGTH;
            $0 = substr($0, RLENGTH+1);
        }
    }
    NR!=1 {
        text = substr($0, a[column], a[column+1] ? a[column+1]-a[column] : length);
        sub(text, / +$/, "");
        print text
    }'
```

Depending on what you want to do, calling awk multiple times may not be the best solution. Keep in mind that you can run shell commands from awk with the `system` function.

Answer (score 13):

```
awk -F' {2,}' # means - two or more spaces.
```

or

```
awk -F'  +' # means - one space, then one or more spaces.
```

This commands mean the same - use 2 or more spaces as fields delimiter.