# Parse colon-separated value pairs (nmcli output) and convert to JSON fromat

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, json, jq, nmcli

I've written a [script](https://gist.github.com/kirkins/16e2f18e8db76e812de62762e1c648de) that converts the output of
`nmcli --mode multiline dev wifi` into JSON,
but I'm finding it's inconsistent *(breaks when results have a space)*,
long, and hard to read.

I wonder if it is possible to pipe the results directly into `jq`.

The `nmcli` output (input to my script) looks like this:

```
*:                                       
SSID:                                   VIDEOTRON2255
MODE:                                   Infra
CHAN:                                   11
RATE:                                   54 Mbit/s
SIGNAL:                                 69
BARS:                                   ▂▄▆_
SECURITY:                               WPA1 WPA2
*:                                      * 
SSID:                                   VIDEOTRON2947
MODE:                                   Infra
CHAN:                                   6
RATE:                                   54 Mbit/s
SIGNAL:                                 49
BARS:                                   ▂▄__
SECURITY:                               WPA1 WPA2
```

I'm looking to generate something like this:

```
[{
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2255",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "11",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "69",
    "bars": "▂▄▆_",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2"
},
{
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2947",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "6",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "49",
    "bars": "▂▄__",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2"
}]
```

---

I asked a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399197/awk-f-delimit-by-space-greater-than-1) earlier. This is [the first script](https://gist.github.com/kirkins/16e2f18e8db76e812de62762e1c648de) I wrote based on [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399203/165517). It worked for some of the values but not `security` or `rate`, which have spaces.

Comment: there would a problem: I got error on encountering that crooked `bars` value `"▂▄▆_"`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest could you post your solution and just remove lines with BARS: using grep? It's not that important since bars is likely just determined by signal.

Comment: you got my solution

Comment: Stupid question: Why insist on using `jq` to parse this? `jq` is made for *parsing* JSON, and this is not JSON. OTOH, any other program that can parse this can often easily *produce* JSON ...

Comment: @dirkt I guess you're right, maybe I was wrong assuming `jq` would be a good tool for the job. There is no reason that I would have to use it in my situation.

Comment: There might be a typo in the input file, the _2nd_ `*:` is followed by a `*`. On my system the output of `nmcli --mode multiline dev wifi` never shows lines where `*:` is followed by a `*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script that you linked to is extremely inefficient - you're doing a lot of useless pre-processing...
Use `nmcli` in `--terse` mode since, per the manual, *"this mode is designed and suitable for computer (script) processing"*, specify the desired fields and pipe the output to `jq -sR` e.g.

```
printf '%s' "$(nmcli -f ssid,mode,chan,rate,signal,bars,security -t dev wifi)" | \
jq -sR 'split("\n") | map(split(":")) | map({"network": .[0],
                                             "mode": .[1],
                                             "channel": .[2],
                                             "rate": .[3],
                                             "signal": .[4],
                                             "bars": .[5],
                                             "security": .[6]})'
```

Comment: Wow, that is a really short script, nice job. On my end I always get an extra entry with all null values.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride - if your `jq` doesn't support those options you can always do something like `nmcli -f ssid,mode,chan,rate,signal,bars,security -t dev wifi | awk -F: 'BEGIN{z[1]="network";z[2]="mode";z[3]="channel";z[4]="rate";z[5]="signal";z[6]="bars";z[7]="security";}{if (NR==1){printf "%s", "[{"}else{printf "%s",",{"}}{for (i=1; i<NF; i++){ printf "\"%s\":\"%s\",",z[i],$i};{ printf "\"%s\":\"%s\"}",z[NF],$NF}}END{print "]"}' | jq .`

Comment: Why would you do `printf '%s' "$(nmcli …)" | …` instead of just `nmcli … | …`? Is that to strip off trailing newline(s)?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' -   not my code (see edits); I guess it's related to OP's first comment above (re: the additional entry with all null values)... and also his comments on _agc_'s answer... apparently his version of `nmcli` was printing additional empty lines

Comment: @agc: Why would you do `printf '%s' "$(nmcli …)" | …` instead of just `nmcli … | …`? Is that to strip off trailing newline(s)?

Comment: Alas, I see that agc seems to have gone away.  Well, maybe they’ll come back and see this.

Answer (score 2):

This *GNU* `sed` code isn't `jq`, (it isn't a complex conversion), but it seems to work well enough, (even the *bars* come out OK):

```
nmcli --mode multiline dev wifi | 
sed    '/^*/! {s/^[A-Z]*/\L&/
               s/ssid/network/
               s/: */": "/
               s/$/"/
               {/^sec/!s/$/,/}
               s/^/\t"/}
        1     s/^\*.*/[{/
        /^\*/ s/.*/},\n{/
        $  {p;s/.*/}]/}'
```

Easier to read standalone `pcsvp.sed` script, (save to file, then run `chmod +x pcsvp.sed`):

```
#!/bin/sed -f
# Text lines (the non "*:" lines.)
/^*/! {s/^[A-Z]*/\L&/
       s/ssid/network/
       s/: */": "/
       s/$/"/
       {/^sec/!s/$/,/}
       s/^/\t"/}

# First JSON line
1     s/^\*.*/[{/

# Middle JSON lines.  If a line begins with a '*'...
/^\*/ s/.*/},\n{/

# Last line, close up the JSON.
$     {p;s/.*/}]/}
```

To run that do:

```
nmcli --mode multiline dev wifi | ./pcsvp.sed
```

---

Note: Since there are [doubts about the input file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399222/jq-parse-colon-separated-value-pairs/399661#comment713716_399222), I've opted to use `nmcli` for input instead.  At my location this shows about 50 networks, which makes the resulting output too long to quote here.

If the input sample typo is corrected, `./pcsvp.sed input.txt` outputs:

```
[{
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2255",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "11",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "69",
    "bars": "▂▄▆_",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2"
},
{
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2947",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "6",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "49",
    "bars": "▂▄__",
    "security": "WEP"
}]
```

Comment: This can generate errors with empty lines. I had to use `nmcli --mode multiline dev wifi | sed '/^$/d' | ./scan.sed`. In the end this answer was more reliable because the end product was on Ubuntu 14.04 and the default version of `jq` didn't have the flags used in @don_crissti's answer.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, I didn't know that `nmcli` could output any empty lines.

Comment: I think it's the very last line that is empty

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, With *network-manager* *v1.4.4-1ubuntu3.2*, running `nmcli --mode multiline dev wifi | grep '^$' | wc -l` consistently returns *0*.

Answer (score 1):

Complex **`jq`** solution (with `BARS` line removed as it contains irregular/non-ASCII characters):

Input file `input.txt`:

```
*:                                       
SSID:                                   VIDEOTRON2255
MODE:                                   Infra
CHAN:                                   11
RATE:                                   54 Mbit/s
SIGNAL:                                 69
SECURITY:                               WPA1 WPA2
*:                                      * 
SSID:                                   VIDEOTRON2947
MODE:                                   Infra
CHAN:                                   6
RATE:                                   54 Mbit/s
SIGNAL:                                 49
SECURITY:                               WPA1 WPA2
```

---

The job:

```
jq -sR '[ gsub("[*]: *\n| {2,}";"") | gsub("SSID";"network") | split("\n[*]:[*] +\n";"n")[] 
    | [ capture("(?<key>[^:\n]+):(?<value>[^:\n]+)";"g") | .key |= (. | ascii_downcase) ] 
    | from_entries ]' input.txt
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2255",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "11",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "69",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2"
  },
  {
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2947",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "6",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "49",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2"
  }
]
```

---

Additional approach for another particular input presented/posted on https://pastebin.com/8stHSUeu:

```
jq -sR '[sub("[*]: *[*]\n";"") | gsub(" {2,}";"") | gsub("SSID";"network") 
  | split("\n[*]: *\n";"n")[] 
  | [ capture("(?<key>[^:\n]+):(?<value>[^:\n]+)";"g") | .key |= (. | ascii_downcase) ] 
  | from_entries]' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. I just have one question it fails when I actually use it. Do you think this `Cocotte-invité` causes the issue? https://pastebin.com/8stHSUeu

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, welcome. What is the error message?

Comment: `src/scripts/scan2.sh: line 12:  4640 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) jq -sR '[ gsub("[*]: *\n| {2,}";"") | gsub("SSID";"network") | split("\n[*]:[*] +\n";"n")[] 
    | [ capture("(?<key>[^:\n]+):(?<value>[^:\n]+)";"g") | .key |= (. | ascii_downcase) ] 
    | from_entries ]' /tmp/json_gen`

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, `Cocotte-invité` should not be an issue, but I have noted that your new input is somehow differs from that one in the question. The 1st line in your new input has `*` at the end: `*:                                      *` while the starting line in question's input does not have it

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, check my additional approach

Comment: when I use the additional approach on the pastebin contents I get: `src/scripts/scan2.sh: line 10:  4908 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) jq -sR '[sub("[*]: *[*]\n";"") | gsub(" {2,}";"") | gsub("SSID";"network") 
  | split("\n[*]: *\n";"n")[] 
  | [ capture("(?<key>[^:\n]+):(?<value>[^:\n]+)";"g") | .key |= (. | ascii_downcase) ] 
  | from_entries]' /tmp/json_gen`

Comment: I'm trying to get the second method working but wasn't able. I'm only marking unanswered so I can see the add bounty button. (40 more minutes)

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, *wasn't able* - that's not the description of the problem! Prepare screenshots and share links to input data

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use a tool that understands JSON back and forth. I'd use Python:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import json
import re
import sys

objects = []
obj = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    entry = re.split(':\s*', line.strip(), maxsplit=1) # split on first `:`
    if entry[0] == '*':
        if obj:  # skip a null entry (the first, here)
            obj['network'] = obj.pop('ssid') # rename the SSID entry
            objects.append(obj)
        obj = {} # start a new object for each `*`
        continue
    obj[entry[0].lower()] = entry[1]  # lowercase the key
obj['network'] = obj.pop('ssid') # rename the SSID entry
objects.append(obj)
json.dump(objects, sys.stdout)
```

Gets me:

```
[{"mode": "Infra", "chan": "11", "rate": "54 Mbit/s", "signal": "69", "bars": "\u2582\u2584\u2586_", "security": "WPA1 WPA2", "network": "VIDEOTRON2255"}, {"ssid": "VIDEOTRON2947", "mode": "Infra", "chan": "6", "rate": "54 Mbit/s", "signal": "49", "bars": "\u2582\u2584__", "security": "WPA1 WPA2"}]
```

which, when pretty-printed by `jq` is:

```
[
  {
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "11",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "69",
    "bars": "▂▄▆_",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2",
    "network": "VIDEOTRON2255"
  },
  {
    "ssid": "VIDEOTRON2947",
    "mode": "Infra",
    "chan": "6",
    "rate": "54 Mbit/s",
    "signal": "49",
    "bars": "▂▄__",
    "security": "WPA1 WPA2"
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm just noticing that your output contains an element with a `network` key and one with a `ssid` key.

Comment: Ah, I see now. In each case I do the change for the previous entry, which means the last one is left as-is.

Answer (score 1):

1. *GNU* `sed` and [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) method:

   ```
   nmcli dev wifi | sed 'y/*/ /;1{s/.*/\L&/;s/ssid/network/};s/   */\t/g'  | 
   mlr --p2j --fs '\t' --jvstack --jlistwrap cat
   ```
2. `bash`, text mode `nmcli`, (swiped from [don_chrissti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399718/165517)),
   and [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller):

   ```
   h=ssid:mode:chan:rate:signal:bars:security
   { echo ${h/ssid/network} ; nmcli -f ${h//:/,} -t dev wifi ; } | \
   mlr --c2j --fs ':' --jvstack --jlistwrap cat
   ```

Comment: The right combination of `nmcli`'s output formats and `mlr`'s many input formats might provide a way to avoid the use of `bash` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Using `csvjson` from the `csvkit` toolkit to create the JSON document directly from the `nmcli` command:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -- SSID MODE CHAN RATE SIGNAL BARS SECURITY

( IFS=:; printf '%s\n' "$*"
  IFS=,; nmcli -g "$*" device wifi ) |
csvjson -d :
```

The first `printf` creates a `:`-delimited CSV header for the `cvsjson` command created from the positional parameters set at the start of the script, and the `nmcli` command gets a comma-delimited list of the same parameters as the option-argument to its `-g` (`--get-values`) option.  The `nmcli` command will create what amounts to `:`-delimited CSV output, and this, together with the simplistic CSV header, is parsed by `csvjson` to produce a JSON document.

The JSON document created will contain an array of objects like

```json
{
  "SSID": "The wireless network",
  "MODE": "Infra",
  "CHAN": 6,
  "RATE": "195 Mbit/s",
  "SIGNAL": 45,
  "BARS": "▂▄__",
  "SECURITY": "WPA2"
}
```

To lowercase the keys and to change `SSID` into `network`, we may use `jq`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -- SSID MODE CHAN RATE SIGNAL BARS SECURITY

( IFS=:; printf '%s\n' "$*"
  IFS=,; nmcli -g "$*" device wifi ) |
csvjson -d : |
jq '.[] | with_entries(if .key == "SSID" then .key |= "network" else .key |= ascii_downcase end)'
```

This is expected to produce an array with entries like

```json
{
  "network": "The wireless network",
  "mode": "Infra",
  "chan": 6,
  "rate": "195 Mbit/s",
  "signal": 34,
  "bars": "▂▄__",
  "security": "WPA2"
}
```