# sed script append to lines starting with?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to write a basic sed script, I want to append to lines that start with `SSID:`. Here is what I'm trying now:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^SSID:/ s/*/},\n{/
```

With the following input:

```
SSID:                                   '2KLIC Guests'
BSSID:                                  F0:9F:C2:21:03:BA
MODE:                                   Infrastructure
FREQ:                                   2437 MHz
RATE:                                   16 MB/s
SIGNAL:                                 100
SECURITY:                               WPA2
ACTIVE:                                 yes
SSID:                                   'CBMS-2.4GHz'
BSSID:                                  10:BE:F5:25:FD:60
MODE:                                   Infrastructure
FREQ:                                   2412 MHz
RATE:                                   16 MB/s
SIGNAL:                                 0
SECURITY:                               WPA WPA2
ACTIVE:                                 no
SSID:                                   'CIK1000M_AC2.4G_3714'
BSSID:                                  D0:60:8C:03:DB:B4
MODE:                                   Infrastructure
FREQ:                                   2422 MHz
RATE:                                   16 MB/s
SIGNAL:                                 0
SECURITY:                               WPA2
ACTIVE:                                 no
```

I also tried escaping the `:`. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What would you like to replace the lines with?  Also why did you put a '\' before `SSID`?

Comment: `},\n{` like the end of a json object @Jesse_b

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole line or just append that value to the end of it?

Comment: Sorry yes, it would be better to append it. @Jesse_b

Comment: it would be better to show the expected result

Comment: Is this a re-post of [parse colon separated value pairs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399222/22142) ?? The fact that you want a 7th field (ACTIVE) doesn't make it any different...

Comment: @don_crissti no it's completely different I'm asking about a single line I'm trying to write in `sed`. I can't use your answer from that question because the flags used in `jq` aren't available (`Unknown option -sR`) in the version on Ubuntu 14.04 and I don't have permission to compile and update libraries on the device.

Comment: Your main mistake was to use `* ` as a pattern to be replaced instead of `.*`. This is not globbing, but regular expression! So, with `/^SSID:/ s/.*/},\n{/` it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just substitute the whole line,

```
s/^SSID:.*/},\n{/
```

If you wanted to keep some or all of the `SSID` line's contents, then try capturing in the initial regex.

```
s/^\(SSID:.*\)/\1\n},\n{/
```

Comment: Thanks first command works but the second returns `line 4: invalid reference \1 on \`s' command's RHS`

Comment: Try it now.  I have backslashed the ``\( \)`` as it is using non-extended regular expressions.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to escape the brackets. `(` isn't a special character in `sed` is it?

Comment: Or is it that when you use `\( \)` it becomes a special character?

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions.

Basically, `sed` (and others) have two modes.  By default, most characters match exactly.  i.e. the expression ``(abc)`` will match ``(abc)``.  In order to use the brackets as groups you must escape them, the expression ``\(abc\)`` will match ``abc`` with a captured group.

With the ``-E`` option these are reversed, and ``(abc)`` will match ``abc`` with a captured group. and you must escape the brackets to match literally.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` expression:

```
/^SSID:/ s/*/},\n{/
```

This is almost correct, but `*` will match a literal `*` (since it's the first character in the regular expression).

Using your way of addressing the line that you'd like to modify:

```
/^SSID:/s/^/},\n{/
```

This would find any line beginning with the string `SSID:` and would substitute in `},\n{` at the start of those lines.

Note that this requires GNU `sed` to interpret the escape sequence `\n` as a newline in the replacement text.

With non-GNU `sed`, you would write

```
/^SSID:/s/^/},\
{/
```

or, if you did this from the command line with a shell like `bash` that understands `$'...'` as a "C string":

```
sed '$/^SSID:/s/^/},\\\n{/'
```

(the `\\\n` is for an escaped `\` followed by `\n`)